# Lookup Ejb 3.0 deployed on Jboss Eap 6.3 from remote client

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6, ejb-3.2, jboss-eap-7

I don't see any issues when I run the server and client on the local worksapce(via eclipse). However there are issues if the client is executed from a different machine than on server or executed from exported client product(i.e. Eclipse rcp).

I also read article on JNDI and various online blogs. Please let me know if I am missing anything obvious. Trying to get the remote client working for couple of days now. :(

```
 Object returnValue = context.lookup("ejb:GeoEE/GeoEJB/UserRegistrationService!com.geo.request.ejb.IUserRegistrationService");
```

above line returns Object in local environment and null in case of remote or exported client.

Comment: Is your ejb implementing a remote interface ? Or is declared as remote ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "ejb:" to "/"

If not set, use this properties to init context(replace server and port):

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
```